# Angular build for production error with PrimeNG

Tags: angular, primeng, production

I am trying to build Angular 8 application for production and I got these errors.
Any advice how to fix it?

```
ERROR in ./node_modules/primeng/fesm5/primeng-table.js
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-optimizer/src/build-optimizer/webpack-loader.js):
TypeError: Cannot read property 'kind' of undefined
    at isAngularDecoratorMetadataExpression 
ERROR in ./node_modules/primeng/fesm5/primeng-paginator.js
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-optimizer/src/build-optimizer/webpack-loader.js):
TypeError: Cannot read property 'kind' of undefined
    at isAngularDecoratorMetadataExpression (C:\Synechron\edms\WebApp\ClientApp\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-optimizer\src\transforms\scrub-file.js:265:35)
ERROR in ./node_modules/primeng/fesm5/primeng-dropdown.js
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-optimizer/src/build-optimizer/webpack-loader.js):
TypeError: Cannot read property 'kind' of undefined
    at isAngularDecoratorMetadataExpression (C:\Synechron\edms\WebApp\ClientApp\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-optimizer\src\transforms\scrub-file.js:265:35)
ERROR in ./node_modules/primeng/fesm5/primeng-tooltip.js
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-optimizer/src/build-optimizer/webpack-loader.js):
TypeError: Cannot read property 'kind' of undefined
    at isAngularDecoratorMetadataExpression (C:\Synechron\edms\WebApp\ClientApp\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-optimizer\src\transforms\scrub-file.js:265:35)
ERROR in ./node_modules/ngx-doc-viewer/fesm5/ngx-doc-viewer.js
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-optimizer/src/build-optimizer/webpack-loader.js):
TypeError: Cannot read property 'kind' of undefined
    at isAngularDecoratorMetadataExpression (C:\Synechron\edms\WebApp\ClientApp\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-optimizer\src\transforms\scrub-file.js:265:35)
```

Comment: Have you tried the `npm cache clean` and then `npm install` then do the production build

Answer (score 2):

I was facing the same issue so i downgraded my library from "primeng": "^9.0.0-rc.2" to "primeng": "^8.1.1" and this issue has been solved.

Answer (score 1):

You can also update to "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.803.20"
as discussed [here](https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor4-angular/issues/78)

Comment: It works, I faced this when upgrade primeng to 9.0.0! Thanks so much!